# Finding smallest value in array and storing in subarray most efficently

Tags: arrays, pseudocode, minimum

Given an array A, calculate a new array B of size n, such that 
B[i] = min (0 ≤ j ≤i) A[j]. In other words, B[i] should store the minimum element in the subarray of A with indices from 0 to i, inclusive.

`Input:  A[7, 3, 4, 2, 15, 11, 16, 7, 18, 9, 11, 10]`

`Output: B[7, 3, 3, 2,  2,  2,  2, 2,  2, 2,  2,  2]`

I'm trying to create the most efficient algorithm for solving this problem. My attempt at psuedocode.

```
minElement(A):
 B[n]; //empty array
  for(i = 0; i < A.length()-1; i++)
   if(A[i] < everything currently in B[])
    B[i] = A[i]
```

I'm having a hard time trying to implement the logic.

Comment: Psuedo code is fine, I just don't know how to compare everything already inside B so far, which starts empty and progressively stores the smallest value encountered in A.

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable `currentMin` to keep track of the minimum value in the portion of the input array processed.

```
func calculate(nums:[Int]) -> [Int] {
    guard !nums.isEmpty else { return [] }
    var currentMin = nums[0]

    var output: [Int] = []
    for num in nums {
        currentMin = min(currentMin, num)
        output.append(currentMin)
    }

    return output
}
```

So inside the for loop you can update the `currentMin` variable and append its value to output.

> The provided implementation is in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
a<- input array;
b<- input array;
int m=a[1]
for 1 to a.length:
    m=min(m,a[i]);
    b[i]=m;
end;
```

implementation  in java:

```
public class demo {
public static void main(String[]args){
    int array[]={7, 3, 4, 2, 15, 11, 16, 7, 18, 9, 11, 10};
    int b[]=new int[array.length];
    int min=array[0];
    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        min=Math.min(min,array[i]);
        b[i]=min;
    }
    for (int i:b){
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}
 }//prints  7 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The most *time* efficient algorithm depends on the language. If a language supports a built-in, efficient `min()` function for arrays, then you can use a pre-calculated absolute minimum variable to exit early out of the for loop. This will, on average, be faster, provided the array is above a certain minimum length.

Of course, you also need a rolling minimum variable as well.

**Pseudo-Code:**

```
minElement(A):
  B[n]; //empty array
  absoluteMin = min(A)
  rollingMin = A[0]
  for(i = 0; i < A.length()-1; i++)
    if(A[i] < rollingMin): rollingMin = A[i]
    B[i] = rollingMin
    if(rollingMin == absoluteMin): exit for
```

**Python Implementation:** <sup><sub>(See [here](http://tpcg.io/tgBwaU) for working example with timings.)</sub></sup>

```python
A = [7, 3, 4, 2, 15, 11, 16, 7, 18, 9, 11, 10]
B = []
absoluteMin = min(A)
rollingMin = A[0]
for value in A:
    if value<rollingMin: rollingMin = value
    B.append(rollingMin)
    if rollingMin==absoluteMin: break
B += [absoluteMin]*(len(A)-len(B))
```

Note that, on average, as the array gets longer, the code above gets faster compared to the equivalent without the absolute minimum parts (shown below). Your sample array is actually below the minimum length required to show a speed improvement. The break-even point is roughly double this length.

```python
A = [7, 3, 4, 2, 15, 11, 16, 7, 18, 9, 11, 10]
B = []
rollingMin = A[0]
for value in A:
    if value<rollingMin: rollingMin = value
    B.append(rollingMin)
```